# How to pass a symbol as a keyword argument?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I export a few symbols from a package and use them internally in a case statement.  I'd like to pass one of the symbols (e.g. medium-size) as a keyword argument to a generic method, like this:

```
(solve problem :optimize-for :medium-size :another-keyword t)
```

but this gives an "odd number of &KEY arguments" error.  Am I misunderstanding something fundamental about symbols or keyword arguments?

Comment: If `medium-size` is exported from your package, it should be `packagename:medium-size`, not `:medium-size`.

Comment: Show the argument list of the generic function. You're probably missing one of the positional arguments.

Comment: The value of a keyword argument can be anything, there's nothing special about using symbols.

Comment: Thanks, Barmar, it was one of the positional arguments.  Please make that comment an answer and I'll give you the credit.

Comment: Without seeing the argument list of the function, I can't provide a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is unexpected behaviour, if `solve` has been defined in a manner similar to:

```
(defun solve (problem &key optimize-for another-keyword)
  ...)
```

However, if you have exported the symbol `medium-size` from `your-package`, it would normally be referred to as `'your-package:medium-size` (or, if you have imported `your-package`, just `'medium-size`).